# After insert update trigger is doubling the values

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am tryting to do a trigger that updates one field when another is inserted. The tables are in the image below.

[These are my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZtUN.png)

So, I have to update tha "saldo" (means balance in portuguese) in the contas table, whenever a transaction is inserted in "transacoes" table (transacoes means transaction). And if "tipo_de_movimento"(means type of transaction) in categorias(means categories) table is equal to 'revenue' (realizada means fullfilled)i should sum the value to the "saldo" field and if "tipo_de_movimento" ='Despesa'(means expense), i should subtract that value to the "saldo" field.

So, I created this trigger

```
ON [dbo].[TRANSACOES]

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

begin

update CONTAS set saldo = saldo + i.VALOR
from inserted i, TRANSACOES t, contas c, CATEGORIAS cat
where i.IDTRANSACAO= t.IDTRANSACAO 
and i.ESTADO = 'Realizada' 
and i.IDCONTA = c.IDCONTA
and i.IDCATEGORIA = cat.IDCATEGORIA
and  cat.TIPO_DE_MOVIMENTO ='Receita'

update CONTAS set saldo = saldo - i.VALOR
from inserted i, TRANSACOES t, contas c, CATEGORIAS cat
where i.IDTRANSACAO= t.IDTRANSACAO 
and i.ESTADO = 'Realizada' 
and i.IDCONTA = c.IDCONTA
and i.IDCATEGORIA = cat.IDCATEGORIA
and  cat.TIPO_DE_MOVIMENTO ='Despesa'

end
```

But the problem I have is that, my saldo field, whenever I insert a value in transacoes, is the double of what it was supposed to be.

So, if i Insert this:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACOES VALUES(4,8,2,1000,'20201210','Teste Right','Transfer','Recibo','Realizada')
```

The value added to the saldo field should be 1000, but instead it adds 2000, so It adds the value twice(?)

So, can someone tell me what Is happening here?

I am a bit clueless as why is this happening, I am new to triggers, so I am sorry If i dind't provide enough details.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Is it possible that after inserting the transaction row, you're updating something on the same row as part of the process?

Comment: Rather than writing a trigger for this, you might want to consider putting logic to calculate the balance in a view instead. If *necessary*, you may also be able to make that an indexed view so that the balance is automatically recalculated and stored by SQL Server. Manually maintaining this balance information just opens up the possibility of the balance being inconsistent with the original data (as you're discovering)

Answer (score 0):

In general, update sets only one/single value per row (even if there are multiple values matching the row). It is not possible for the update in the trigger of TRANSACOES to update CONTAS multiple times per row. Most likely there is a second trigger on TRANSACOES and that 2nd trigger fires and updates CONTAS again or a trigger on CONTAS which adds the value a second time.

The fact that "update sets only one/single value per row" will cause another problem in the trigger as is:
If you try to insert two transactions for the same IDCONTA then only one of the two VALORs will be added to the SALDO ( == two values matching the CONTA.IDCONTA but update can only set **one** value per row)

```
insert TRANSACOES (IDCONTA, VALOR)
values(123, 500), (123, 1000) 
--then the update in the trigger (as it is written) 
--will either update CONTA.IDCONTA[123] with +500 or +1000, but not with +1500.
```

Another issue is the update of existing rows in TRANSACOES: If an existing 'Realizada' & 'Receita' transaction gets updated from VALOR = 140 --> VALOR = 150, then the corresponding CONTA should be increased by (150-140=+10), but the trigger's update sets CONTA by +150 (=inserted.VALOR).

In a trigger created FOR INSERT, UPDATE --> inserted "table" will have values if any rows are inserted or updated. The deleted "table" will always be empty for insert. If you would like to have one update statement for insert&update DML actions, the inserted should be left joined with deleted.
A form of the update statement in the trigger could be:

```
...........trigger AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

--if inserted is "empty", no rows were inserted or updated..just do nothing, return
if not exists(select * from inserted)
begin
    return
end

update c
set saldo = saldo + isnull(aggr.contaVALOR, 0) --better safe (where filters out null)
from CONTAS as c
JOIN
(
    select 
        i.IDCONTA, 
        sum
        (
            /*if inserted/transaction is 'Realizada'&'Receita' add i.VALOR, in any other case NULL::ISNULL(null, 0) = 0*/
            isnull(case when i.ESTADO = 'Realizada' and icat.TIPO_DE_MOVIMENTO = 'Receita' then i.VALOR end, 0)
            -  /*<--subtract*/
            /*if deleted/transaction was 'Realizada'&'Receita' subtract d.VALOR, in any other case NULL::ISNULL(null, 0) = 0*/
            isnull(case when d.ESTADO = 'Realizada' and dcat.TIPO_DE_MOVIMENTO = 'Receita' then d.VALOR end, 0)
        ) as contaVALOR
    from inserted as i
        join CATEGORIAS as icat on i.IDCATEGORIA = icat.IDCATEGORIA
    left join 
    (
        deleted as d 
        join CATEGORIAS as dcat on d.IDCATEGORIA = dcat.IDCATEGORIA
    ) on i.IDTRANSACAO = d.IDTRANSACAO
    where 'Realizada' in (i.ESTADO, d.ESTADO) --status of transaction is or changed from/to Realizada
      and 'Receita' in (icat.TIPO_DE_MOVIMENTO, dcat.TIPO_DE_MOVIMENTO) --category of transaction is or changed from/to 'Receita'
    group by i.IDCONTA
) as aggr on c.IDCONTA = aggr.IDCONTA
where aggr.contaVALOR <> 0;
```

Even if the above worked for new transactions or when updating/changing existing transactions (statuses and categories included) [note: code has not been executed at all, not tested whatsoever] there is a major caveat in the approach of keeping balance with triggers: what happens if an existing CATEGORIA changes from 'Receita' to 'xyz'? The CATEGORIAS table gets updated but this will not fire any TRANSACOES trigger and all the calculated SALDO will get instantly invalidated.

As commented in the question, keeping real-time balance with triggers is tricky and gets messy easily very quickly. In addition, the balance logic is spread in multiple places (for your example, you would need two triggers to keep some sort of accurate saldo, two places of saldo concern).
A view, would consolidate all the logic in one place/statement and it will provide better control when this logic needs to change.